# How do I get a Blender exporter script to run from the command line?

Tags: python, command-line, export, blender

I am trying to export some objects from blender into a proprietary format. I'd like the script I write to be able to export the objects from blender from the File drop down and from the command line. I am using blender 2.66 on ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Below is the file I currently am trying to get to run.

```
# Required Blender information.
bl_info = {
           "name": "My Exporter",
           "author": "",
           "version": (1, 0),
           "blender": (2, 65, 0),
           "location": "File > Export > Test (.tst)",
           "description": "",
           "warning": "",
           "wiki_url": "",
           "tracker_url": "",
           "category": "Import-Export"
          }

# Import the Blender required namespaces.
import bpy
from bpy_extras.io_utils import ExportHelper


# The main exporter class.
class MyExporter(bpy.types.Operator, ExportHelper):
   bl_idname       = "test.tst";
   bl_label        = "My Exporter";
   bl_options      = {'PRESET'};

   filename_ext    = ".tst";

   object_count    = 0;

   def __init__(self):
      pass

   def execute(self, context):
      print("Execute was called.");

      # Parse all the objects in the scene.
      return {'FINISHED'};

   def export_object(self, gameObject):
      if (gameObject.type != "MESH"):
         print("Object was not of type mesh.");
      else:
         object_count += 1;

      return;


# Define a function to create the menu option for exporting.
def create_menu(self, context):
   self.layout.operator(MyExporter.bl_idname,text="test (.tst)");

# Define the Blender required registration functions.
def register():
   """
   Handles the registration of the Blender Addon.
   """
   bpy.utils.register_module(__name__);
   bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_export.append(create_menu);

def unregister():
   """
   Handles the unregistering of this Blender Addon.
   """
   bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__);
   bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_export.remove(create_menu);

# Handle running the script from Blender's text editor.
if (__name__ == "__main__"):
   print("Registering.");
   register();

   print("Executing.");

   # I have tried with these lines uncommented to force it to run
   # the execute function, but I get an error saying:
   #    exporter = MyExporter();
   #    TypeError: bpy_struct.__new__(type): expected a single argument

   #exporter = MyExporter();
   #exporter.execute(bpy.context.scene);
```

I have tried the following command:

```
blender model.blend --background --python myexporter.py
```

From which I get the following as output:

```
Note: No (valid) '~/.config/blender/2.66/config/startup.blend' found,
      fall back to built-in default.

Read new prefs: ~/.config/blender/2.66/config/userpref.blend
found bundled python: ~/blender/2.66/python
read blend: ~/model.blend
Registering.
Executing.

Blender quit
```

The execute function from the MyExporter class never seems to get called. I even tried calling the execute function directly but, if you read the comment above that area, I seem to be missing something there as well.

Everything works fine when the script is added as an add-on to blender. It calls execute perfectly. So at least I have half of it working.

Thank you in advance for any help you can give me. If I made a stupid mistake I apologize, I am learning python at the same time as I write this script.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I finally figured this out and thought it would be a good idea to come back and share the answer. First here is the file that works.

```
# Required Blender information.
bl_info = {
           "name": "My Exporter",
           "author": "",
           "version": (1, 0),
           "blender": (2, 65, 0),
           "location": "File > Export > Test (.tst)",
           "description": "",
           "warning": "",
           "wiki_url": "",
           "tracker_url": "",
           "category": "Import-Export"
          }

# Import the Blender required namespaces.
import sys, getopt

import bpy
from bpy_extras.io_utils import ExportHelper



# The main exporter class.
class MyExporter(bpy.types.Operator, ExportHelper):
   bl_idname       = "export_scene.my_exporter";
   bl_label        = "My Exporter";
   bl_options      = {'PRESET'};

   filename_ext    = ".tst";

   object_count    = 0;

   def __init__(self):
      pass

   def execute(self, context):
      print("Execute was called.");

      self.parse_command_line_options();

      if (self.filepath == ""):
         print("No sutable filename was provided to save to.");
         return {'FINISHED'};

      # Get all the mesh objects in the scene.
      objList = [object for object in bpy.context.scene.objects if object.type == 'MESH'];

      # Now process all the objects that we found.
      for gameObject in objList:
         self.export_object(gameObject);

      # Parse all the objects in the scene.
      return {'FINISHED'};


   def export_object(self, gameObject):
      if (gameObject.type != "MESH"):
         print("Object was not of type mesh.");
      else:
         self.object_count += 1;

      return;


   def parse_command_line_options(self):
      modelFile = "";
      myArgs = [];
      argsStartPos = 0;

      if (("--" in sys.argv) == False):
         return;

      argsStartPos = sys.argv.index("--");
      argsStartPos += 1;
      myArgs = sys.argv[argsStartPos:];

      try:
         opts, args = getopt.getopt(myArgs, 'hm:', ["help", "model-file="]);
      except getOpt.GetoptError:
         print("Opt Error.");
         return;

      for opt, arg in opts:
         if (opt in ("-h", "--help")):
            print("Run this as the following blender command.");
            print("\tblender <blend file> --background --python <script file> -- -m <output file>");
         elif (opt in ("-m", "--model-file")):
            modelFile = arg;

      if (modelFile != ""):
         self.filepath = modelFile;



# Define a function to create the menu option for exporting.
def create_menu(self, context):
   self.layout.operator(MyExporter.bl_idname,text="test (.tst)");

# Define the Blender required registration functions.
def register():
   """
   Handles the registration of the Blender Addon.
   """
   bpy.utils.register_module(__name__);
   bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_export.append(create_menu);

def unregister():
   """
   Handles the unregistering of this Blender Addon.
   """
   bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__);
   bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_export.remove(create_menu);


# Handle running the script from Blender's text editor.
if (__name__ == "__main__"):
   print("Registering.");
   register();

   print("Executing.");
   bpy.ops.export_scene.my_exporter();
```

The key things that I was missing were setting the bl_idname for my exporter class incorrectly and then the call of bpy.ops.export_scene.my_exporter();

More information about what I messed up can be found here: http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_66_release/bpy.ops.html

Now since I also wanted this to run from the command line and not just the File drop down menu, I added a parse function to parse the command line options sent to Blender. Blender has a switch '--' that defines the end of blender argument input, so if that switch is detected then I grab any arguments after it and parse those as my scripts arguments. This, so far, seems to work perfectly.

Currently, the model file supports -h to print some help information and -m to specify the file to save the conversion data to.

Well, I hope that this information helps someone else out there. Good luck.

Update: If you see one or more messages like the following on the command line when running your script then use the answer from this [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1903/after-updating-to-blender-2-68-driver-scripts-are-no-longer-automatically-excecu) to solve that problem.

```
skipping driver 'alpha * auto', automatic scripts are disabled
```

Comment: Hi @Jason Smith, it is really great work, where we want to put this script in the blender, and how can we run this ?

Comment: Well, I was running this from the command line, as the title states, so I used something like this:  

blender <blend_file> --background --python Exporter.py

Comment: If you want to run this from inside blender as an add-on that is possible as well. For that I refer you to here. http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Extensions/Python/Add-Ons

Comment: Hi @Jason Smith, thanks for the hint, and i want to know how to pass the file as the argument to this python script ?

Comment: Hi @Json Smith, i have successfully installed blender and executed your script with the command line, now am getting  `No sutable filename was provided to save to.` how can i give the input file to export ?

Comment: can i use arguments to pass the input files? let me know am waiting for your answer

Comment: @JothiKannan Sorry, I got busy and forgot to come back to this. The exporter is set to be run on a per blend file basis. so If you are trying to export multiple blender files just create a loop in your program or script to call:  blender <blend_file> --background --python Exporter.py

Comment: @JothiKannan If you really need to specify variables to send to script then after Exporter.py in the above command you can add a -- followed by any information you need to pass to the script. These flags can then be parsed in the parse_command_line_options function. As an example -m is currently handled. So if you call the script with "blender <blend_file> --background --python Exporter.py -- -m <output_file_name>" then the file should be saved to output_file_name.

Comment: @JothiKannan I just reread your comment a few posts up: If you receive the error "No sutable filename was provided to save to." Then you just need to pass the command line flag -m to tell it where to save the model.  "blender <blend_file> --background --python Exporter.py -- -m <output_file_name>"